# Can you specify the assembly [DLL] name in a master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages, msdn

I have the following code in my master page file

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.Master.cs" Inherits="Web.Site1, V1" %>
```

I have the following error

```
The type 'Web.Site1' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\64948957\cd9589ec\assembly\dl3\7c1855b4\03471781_3a47d101\V1.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\64948957\cd9589ec\assembly\dl3\9fffc304\b40ca480_3a47d101\V2.DLL
```

From the error message it would seem that asp.net cannot differentiate between the assembly DLLs if they contain a class with the same name and namespace even though the assembly is specified in the "inherits" declaration in my master page ".master" file.

Specifying a type in a web.config file is working correctly and can be seen using a similar format in a question I have asked previously here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599735/884132

*"namespace, assembly"*

It is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1917005/884132 that specifying the assembly and namespace names using the same format for the inherits property as the type property in the web.config will work.

**Is this actually true and does the inherits property support providing an assembly name?**

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do here is to clean up (delete files) the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder and recompile the project. You can also check the solution posted: [Asp.net temporary file cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137457/asp-net-temporary-files-cleanup)